# DLL build with OCI and MySQL and LabView keeps failing

Tags: mysql, visual-c++, dll, labview, oracle-call-interface

NOTE: I've been successfully building these DLLs that can be executed by LabView  for over 15 years now (*and Excel too, recently*). As a matter of fact, LabView can view all the entry points into the DLL, it just can't execute them.

Having taken out MySQL and Oracle/OCI functionality, LabView can now execute my code properly. It appears the culprits are in, `libmysql.lib` and `oci.lib`

I guess the easy way to replace the MySQL library is with MariaDB. Any suggestions for OCI?

Comment: I don't think this is related to your problem, but `SDK_ROOT` and `MSVC_ROOT` don't have closing double-quotes; `INCLUDES` and `LIB` don't have opening double-quotes; and `CC` doesn't have an extension.

Does `sql_driver` behave well with a null pointer?

Comment: Thanks, but those aren't problems and `sql_driver` does work well. I'm going to amend this post because when I disable both mysql and oracle function, the ODBC-only version compiles and works well

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the linking and build were fine. With the instantclient installation Oracle doesn't make any changes to the registry so that the OS can find `OCI.DLL`. When I used LabView to load `OCI.DLL` from the instantclient directory, those functions loaded fine, so I then placed `OCI.DLL` in the same directory as my LabView source and everything worked as it should.

The MySQL issue was resolved with linking to `mysqlclient.lib` instead of `libmysql.lib`

I think it's important to note that Oracle provided no help or support.